# Violation of uniqueness in primary key when using inheritance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using inheritance in PostgreSQL but there is a big problem while using it.
I have a Parent table and 2 Child Tables and I don'tknow how to insert a data in these tables.
The uniqueness of Parent primary key become violated when I insert some data into child tables.

The parent table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
  pid int not null,
  pAttr1 int not null,
  primary key (pid)
)
```

The childs are:

```
CREATE TABLE child1 (
  ChAttr1 int not null
) INHERITS (Parent)

CREATE TABLE child2(
  ChAttr2 int not null
) INHERITS (Parent)
```

When i use these INSERTs :

```
INSERT into Parent values (1,10)
INSERT into Child1 values (1,20,30) --1 for pk, 20 for pAttr1 & 30 for ChAttr1
INSERT into Child2 values (1,50,60)
```

Then there are 3 entities with primary key of 1 in Parent table!!!

Comment: Your child tables both have one column, but you INSERT 3 columns into each.

Comment: According to PostgreSQL documentation when you want to insert into a child table you should use parent attributes too. But this is not the main problem. The problem is why the Primary key uniqueness has been violated !! @jarlh

Comment: You should also post the actual error string you got (or most of it).

Comment: There are no errors!! All 3 records have been added to Parent table. @Sarwara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS):

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint. Thus, in the terms of the above example:
>
> - If we declared `cities.name` to be `UNIQUE` or a `PRIMARY KEY`, this would not stop the `capitals` table from having rows with names duplicating rows in `cities`. And those duplicate rows would by default show up in queries from `cities`.

If you `SELECT * FROM parent`, PostgreSQL effectively executes:

```
SELECT pid, pattr1 FROM parent
UNION ALL
SELECT pid, pattr1 FROM child1
UNION ALL
SELECT pid, pattr1 FROM child2;
```

You can look at the `EXPLAIN` output to verify that.

Comment: Thanks. I found out what is the problem. But now what is the solution? How can I prevent this duplication? I tried to define pid as primary key in child table but this solution didn't answer too!

Comment: You cannot avoid that problem with inheritance.

Comment: I designed my Entity Diagram based on inheritance. You mean i should change my design to avoid this issue? How programmers deal with this problem in big projects? I think avoid using inheritance is not the only solution. Certainly there should be solutions to use inheritance and deal with uniqueness issues. You have any idea?

Comment: No, I have no good idea. You can fiddle around with triggers and `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, but that'd cost a lot of performance and is complicated. You should avoid inheritance in your situation.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my time <3